# How to define a global variable inside a Flutter applicaion?

Tags: flutter, global-variables, media-queries, size, device

I like to have a global variable like `deviceHeight` that I can use it inside different widgets within different files of my application, but I don't know how?

This is the `deviceHeight` variable that I want to have access to everywhere inside my application:

```
    deviceHeight = (mediaQuery.size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height - mediaQuery.padding.top);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text(
              'Personal Expenses',
            ),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
                  onTap: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Personal Expenses',
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
              ),
            ],
          );

final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

Also like to have another one like:

```
final isLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
```

Where should I put the definition of these variables and how to import/use them through different places in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

late double width;
late double height;

void main() {
  width= ui.window.physicalSize.width / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  height = ui.window.physicalSize.height / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
}
```

But if you are building a web (flutter web is not that good right now) or windows application where the application width and height can be change by user by resizing the windows, you can try and use [Layout builder Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html), the constrain contain the width and height of the device. layout builder will reload whenever the screen size update.
It Good for responsive UI. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mp-Ok00WZE&t=127s&ab_channel=TheFlutterWay)